# Trouble installing Object Aid in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse-plugin, objectaid

I tried installing Object Aid in Eclipse Luna.

I got error, after referring search engine, i got to know 
that I need to extract Graphical Editor Framework in dropins directory.

I did so but still unable to install Object Aid.

Please tell me from scratch. How to install Graphical Editor Framework and Object Aid.

Thanks

Comment: Take a peej at http://www.objectaid.com/installation and also it might help if you paste in the error message?